# How to expand correctly a variable in sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have this file:

```
user0:
  hash: $2a$12$DA47ZutoC.89KDePyBK.yubz.2vfEiLi28ENBRuyoNf.px3.vHINq
user1:
  hash: $2a$12$Auk82xqdbgFb4AJKyvSuWOKTQivuHhJZwckLii5/a5ILhCke0sddS
user3:
  hash: $2a$12$QW/dCK7CqE5s87OIk8QBeeBYVvD5tjbd46jH9wVD9YMWW31KQEA1y
user4:
  hash: $2a$12$60ds1ivJzM/DexIBYUilzO4BPjumsdTOETAHoopIxabffoWiDEkum
```

and a bash script to change the hash associated to a username. 
For example to change user1 hash, i would use:

```
sed -i "/user1:/{n;s,.*,  hash: NEW_HASH/}" MY_FILE
```

Now, in the script I have variables, and so actually my previous example is:

```
sed -i "/$1:/{n;s,.*,  hash: $hash/}" "$users"
```

My problem is that the `$hash` parameter has got also `/` characters, resulting in a sed error like this:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unterminated `s' command
```

How to correct my command in order to let it expand `hash` variable correctly? I tried some combinations of `'` and `"` commands but without results. Any help?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using `,` as the delimiter for the `s` command it should be:

```
sed -i "/$1:/{n;s,.*,  hash: $hash,;}" "$users"
----------------------------------^ comma, not /
```

I've also appended a `;` after the `s` command. Some implementations of `sed` need that.